# javascript - drawing circle in google map - google.maps.Circle - exception - map is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, exception

I'ved got these piece of code for displaying a circle in google map:

```
  const radiusCircle = new google.maps.Circle({  // <-- this works
    strokeColor: "#FF0000", //red
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "#FF0000", //red
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map,
    center: { lat: alatitude, lng: alongitude },
    radius: aattendance_radius,
  });


  // this is to display division radiuses
  if (div_array_var)
  {

    // merge duplicates
    clean_div_array_var = [...new Set(div_array_var)];


    for (i = 0; i < clean_div_array_var.length; i++)
    {
        if (clean_div_array_var[i] != null)
        {   

                radiusCircle3 = new google.maps.Circle({  // <-- this DOESNT works
                  strokeColor: "#FF00FF", //blue
                  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                  strokeWeight: 2,
                  fillColor: "#FF00FF", //blue
                  fillOpacity: 0.35,
                  map,
                  center: { lat: clean_div_array_var[i].location_lon, lng: clean_div_array_var[i].location_lat },
                  radius: clean_div_array_var[i].attendance_radius,
                });


        }
            
    }

  }
```

the javascript code which is outside the loop

```
radiusCircle <-- this works
```

but

```
radiusCircle3 <-- DOESNT work
```

which is inside a for loop DOESNT work, and throws the exception below

```
(index):1205 Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> ((index):1205)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDivElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.trigger (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap.min.js:6)
    at HTMLDivElement.d (jquery.min.js:3)
```

how can i solve this, why inside the loop didnt work ?

Comment: The posted code works for me (if I define the missing variables).  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.  [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/x1Lghfqe/) Note that your variables seem to be named backwards (`**lat**: clean_div_array_var[i].**location_lon**, **lng**: clean_div_array_var[i].**location_lat**`), and the comments are confusing (`"#FF00FF", //blue`, `#FF00FF` is not blue...)

Comment: According to the docs the `CircleOptions` interface should have a `map` property to which you pass the map instance object, although it seems to work without declaring that property...

Answer (score 1):

The error is that `map` is undefined, not `maps` - the line you've highlighted doesn't seem to be the problem.

You need to define the map that is being passed into `Circle()` - for example:

```
const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: { lat: 37.09, lng: -95.712 },
    mapTypeId: "terrain",
  });
```

It may be that you've defined this above in a block scope not accessible by the loop?

Comment: my map is defined simply like this. its funny, when I move that code to the top nearer to the map defined, it works. the original place, well radiusCircle works but not radiusCircle3.